# Rails returning validation error message from model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am calling an import method in my controller that imports a file. If in the import it tries to save the object and fails a model validation, how would I return the validation error messages to the `project_data_path` (or some other way of getting back to the index view)?

I tried an if statement in the controller, but it just gives me a validation failed error

**Controller**

```
def import
  if Datum.import(params[:file],params[:project_id])
    redirect_to project_data_path, notice: "data imported."
  else
    redirect_to project_data_path #if import fails, need to send errors
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
def self.import(file, proj_id)
    ##.. working logic that imports file into datum..##

    ## below works fine if there are no validation errors
    datum.save! ##model validation error happens here

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save!` throws an exception, while `save` just returns `true` or `false`. Just remove the exclamation mark.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue, after removing the !, I was able to add `return datum.errors` to read the errors

Comment: @HoosierCoder congratulations!